# How to understand stdio.h are different on different operating systems

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, stdio, minix

First of all, I am talking about UNIX-like systems.

I look at the definition of the "FILE" struct at Mac OS, Linux, Minix and K&R C book, they are all different.

In K&R C book, it is quite clear

```
typedef struct _iobuf{
    int cnt;
    char *ptr;
    char *base;
    int  flag;
    int  fd;
} FILE;
```

on Mac OS, it has more stuff inside the struct.

on Linux (3.0), it is

```
typedef _IO_FILE FILE;
```

The header says "Define ISO C stdio on top of C++ iostreams." Em... ? ( C on Linux are implemented by C++ ? Shouldn't it be opposite?)
Looks like _IO_FILE definition is in libio.h

on Minix, the definition is quite similar as K&R.

My unstanding was stdio.h should be part of C. The first C compiler is implemented by assembly language. And C should be independent of OS type.

machine code on HW -> asm -> C -> more complicated C -> UNIX

And now, there are different stdio.h on different OSs (all kinds of UNIX) and the compilers are all gcc.

How to understand this?

Thanks a lot,
Alfred

Comment: How does it matter whether the definitions are different or not? If you're doing anything with a `FILE *`, other than passing it to stdio.h functions that make use of it, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Doesn't matter as an user. However, I am learning system level stuff. So it matters to me to understand it.

Comment: In that case, unless you're interested in learning the innards of all major OSes out there, I suggest you narrow it down to the ones you're interested in and delve deeper into those. As the answers below point out, stuff like this is very much OS dependent.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please also comment on my comments below? See if I really get it.

Answer (score 5):

The `FILE` struct is platform dependent and its fields are used internally by the C library. You shouldn't be relying on what's inside it.

Comment: So C library is not part of the C programming language itself, am I right?

Comment: Can I understand it in this way: the compiler like gcc just implement code generation for most primitive C instructions. And C libraries are not part of these instructions. Then one can implement other C libraries using those primitive C instructions. One can also implement an OS and its API using those primitive C instructions. So it can have different implementations of C libraries. Am I right about this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library - the first paragraph explains it quite nicely.

Comment: The implementation is free to the implementor, as long as the outwards interfaces are all conforming.

Comment: So the start point will be primitive C (without any library), then OS and its API (implemented by those primitive C instructions, can be combinations of those primitive C codes), then C and C libraries. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Your own C code should not depend on OS. C headers and internal CRT implementation are OS-dependent. The meaning of cross-platform programming: write the code, compile it in different OS, and it should work. However, underlying tools (C, cross-platform libraries) are interacting with OS-specific API and they are different in different OS.

Of course, you should not use any fields of opaque structures, this breaks platform independent code.